# Can't load website into Iframe

Tags: iframe

I'm trying to insert this website: "http://www.sapo.pt/noticias/tecnologia" into a IFrame:

```
 <html>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.sapo.pt/noticias/tecnologia"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

[But nothing appears on the iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3jiS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open you browser's Developer Tools. Look at the Console. Read the error messages.

> Refused to display '`http://www.sapo.pt/noticias/tecnologia`' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

The site doesn't allow other sites to put it in a frame.